# in datadriven, how to rerun failed tests(rows in excel) alone

Tags: java, selenium, testng, data-driven-tests

I have dataprovider where it reads excel file , each row as one test case data, when I ran this testng test which uses dataprovider for data.

Is there a way to run only failed tests(in the excel which row data gets failed that rows) alone?

Comment: Try to read the values of the column which contains the result and continue only if if is 'Fail'.

Comment: is there a way to create a test case for each row dynamically, so that failed tests in testng report I can rerun. The above solution wont work out for me as I will run my test in different Vms , If i insert the result into dataprovider xml also , there is no gaurantee of picking my test on the same vm